# Asp.Net MVC3 - Linq not working in Razor Views

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I am not sure what went wrong but i could not able top use linq in razor view, but i can use linq in controllers.

for example, i cannot run this code

```
@foreach (char ch in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray().Where(ch=>ch!='a'))
{

}
```

or

```
@Html.EditorFor(e=>e.Id )
```

any solution for this?

**Update**: The problem was that, IDE shows red underline where linq is used. but runs without any problem.

Comment: getting method Where is not found and no suitable extension method is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `Linq` namespace in your view:

```
@using System.Linq
```

---

> The **System.Linq** namespace is in the **System.Core** assembly (**in
>   System.Core.dll**)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.aspx

Comment: unable to import System.Linq - getting Type or Namespace Linq not available in System.

Comment: Just updated my answer - Add a reference, in your project, to the `System.Core` assembly and it should work...